# Jackson: Ignore parent class properties

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

Is there any way I can tell Jackson to ignore properties from parent class while serializing a child class?

```
    class Parent{
      private String parentProperty1;
      private String parentProperty2;
      //getter setter
    }

    @IgnoreParentProperties // I am expecting something like this
    class Child extends Parent{
      private String childProperty1;
      //getter setter
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define & use a [JSON view](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) which omits the inherited fields.

Comment: Seems a better solution :)
Thnx :)

Comment: This solution works fine, but `@JsonView` cannot combine with `@JsonProperty` directly. Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205158/combine-jackson-jsonview-and-jsonproperty

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Views that work well, you can also use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to list names of properties to ignore; this can include parent properties as well.