# Combine Jackson @JsonView and @JsonProperty

Tags: json, properties, annotations, jackson, mapping

Is there a way to not only view/hide fields by using different classes in @JsonView but also define different names (like with @JsonProperty) depending on the view used for each field separately?

Greets & thx!
Tim

Answer (score 4):

My solution involves [Jackson Mixin](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) feature.
I used the same view class to place the different @jsonProperty annotations. This is more convinient than a seperate class, however, now you cannot use inheritence of views. If you need this, you will have to create seperate classes that hold the @jsonProperty annotations and change the mixin modules accordingly.

Here is the object to be serialized:

```
public class Bean
{
    @JsonView({Views.Public.class, Views.Internal.class})
    public String name;

    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    public String ssn;
}
```

The views with the json property annotations

```
public class Views
{
    public static class Public {
        @JsonProperty("public_name")
        public String name;
    }

    public static class Internal {
        @JsonProperty("internal_name")
        public String name;
    }
}
```

The mixin modules, required by Jackson:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PublicModule extends SimpleModule
{
    public PublicModule() {
        super("PublicModule");
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context)
    {
        context.setMixInAnnotations(Bean.class, Views.Public.class);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InternalModule extends SimpleModule
{
    public InternalModule() {
        super("InternalModule");
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context)
    {
        context.setMixInAnnotations(Bean.class, Views.Internal.class);
    }
}
```

test method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Bean bean = new Bean();
    bean.name = "my name";
    bean.ssn = "123-456-789";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(args[0] + ": ");
    try {
        if (args[0].equals("public")) {
            mapper.registerModule(new PublicModule());
            mapper.writerWithView(Views.Public.class).writeValue(System.out, bean);
        } else {
            mapper.registerModule(new InternalModule());
            mapper.writerWithView(Views.Internal.class).writeValue(System.out, bean);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output with two separate invocations:

```
public: 
{"public_name":"my name"}
internal: 
{"ssn":"123-456-789","internal_name":"my name"}
```